# jQuery `Quicksand` plugin not working, how do I use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicksand, jquery-isotope

### Basically.... Get this working... **[JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/SVYFY/)**

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin for filtering items inside 3 UL's. *(Each `<ul></ul>` will have a unlimited amount of list items.)*

The plugin I am using is located at the link below ([Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html)) (along with the documentation & demo).

### **Quicksand:** http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

### **Documentation** http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html

The plugin will basically filter the results of the items contained within my `<ul></ul>`.

I attempted this on a number of occasions, but I am getting no console errors or anything to point me where I am going wrong, and have no idea why its not working.

I have 3 `<ul class="column"></ul>` tags each with list items below them (3 in this case). I need to be able to filter (and animate) all of them, using the plugin.

**I have also made a**  **[- JS Fiddle -](http://jsfiddle.net/SVYFY/)**  **with my code for you to play with. (Quicksand is included as a 'resource').**

The basic structure of my HTML is:

**Menu**

```
<!-- On click of these, filter according to 'data-value' -->
<ul id="definations" class="wrapper">
    <li><a href="javascript:;">all</a></li>
    <li data-value="web"><a href="javascript:;">digital - web</a></li>
    <li data-value="iphone"><a href="javascript:;">digital - mobile</a></li>
    <li data-value="android"><a href="javascript:;">branding & print</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">event</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">motion</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Content to Filter**

```
<div id="portfolio" class="wrapper">
    <ul class="column">
        <li class="work item" data-id="id-1" data-type="iphone" data-title="iPhone" data-project="iPhone and Android App" data-year="2012 Project">
            <a href="javascript:;"><img src="/css/img/product/work-demo1.png" alt="Omega"/></a>
            <a class="view" href="javascript:;"></a>
        </li>

        <li class="work item" data-id="id-2" data-type="android" data-title="Android" data-project="Rich Web Application" data-year="2012 Project">
            <a href="javascript:;"><img src="/css/img/product/work-demo3.png" alt="Description"/></a>
            <a class="view" href="javascript:;"></a>
        </li>

        <li class="work item" data-id="id-3" data-type="web" data-title="Web" data-project="Site Rebrand" data-year="2011 Project">
            <a href="javascript:;"><img src="/css/img/product/work-demo2.png" alt="Description"/></a>
            <a class="view" href="javascript:;"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- I have 3 of the above columns, I would like the filter to act on all of them -->
    <!-- I have only included 1 to keep it short -->
</div>
```

-
Ready: [**JSFiddle!!**](http://jsfiddle.net/SVYFY/)

---

### - Update -

I decided to purchase and use the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin in the end. The examples on the site are great, and I could achieve the effect I needed.
Very customizable and the perfect plugin for what I needed it for. (If your reading this, its probably what your after).
Check it out at: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Tried to help, but get this error immediately in console: `$("#definations").quicksand is not a function`

Comment: Check out the STATUS jsFiddle in my answer. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STATUS:** Here is an example of what you want using the live demo below: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cpmu/1/)

I highly recommend this [tutorial with live demo](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/) that shows an excellent method to use the **Quicksand** plugin. The comments show below include a couple of tips by me explaining how to have clickable links in the navigation.

The markup is very similar yours except in addition to the Quicksand JavaScript file a **separate asset file** is required that configures Quicksand, which your jsFiddle is not using.

To be sure, this asset file is the **Click Event** handler that activates the Quicksand filtering based on your markup layout. For example this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cJPC/) shows 1 of 5 ready to use examples from the Quicksand website that are linked in the [Examples Section](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html#examples). The separate asset file I was referring to can be considered as the jQuery markup in the JavaScript window.

Also note that **jQuery UI Library is required**, and is loaded as an asset in the above jsFiddle.

I created a **Quicksand Demo with Shadowbox**, a lightbox alternative, based on the original demo. It's on the [Shadowbox Forum](http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/Quicksand-Demo-featuring-Shadowbox-tp7303500.html). If you need help with that, visit and post there and I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

this error/bug is 'cause the plugin doesn't work with the latest verions of jQuery. You can solved it with using just old jQuery (1.7.2 i just tryed and it works).

please sorry my english...